# Is "like" used as an adjective by native speakers?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Do native speakers use like as an adjective?  Is it a preferred usage?

Comment: 'Like' as an adjective? Could you give an example? Because *"He is a very **like** person."* makes no sense to me.

Comment: @mikhailcazi: ["My partner and I have like minds."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/like#Adjective)

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I couldn't think what you meant until Reg gave the example, which suggests that the answer is "not often". I think it is rather literary. The compound adjective _like-minded_ is common, but no other context that I can think of.

Comment: The frequency is somewhere between once-in-a-blue-moon and every-so-often.   Perhaps we can rephrase this question.

Answer (score 5):

You have to distinguish between transitive and intransitive uses of the adjective.

- Intransitive *like*, meaning “similar”, occurs only as an attributive (*like minds*, *like considerations*); in predicative positions it is replaced by *alike* (*Their minds are alike*). It is very rare in speech, and even in writing it is not common. The Google Ngram below, which plots the relative literary frequency of *like* and *similar* in a couple of shared contexts, is suggestive, nothing more; but I suspect that if anything it exaggerates the contemporary frequency of attributive *like*, perhaps because the use is still fairly popular in legal writing.

  > [image: ratio of attributive like to attributive similar]
- Transitive *like*, meaning “similar **to**”, is very common in both speech and writing. The Google Ngram below shows that in writing it has lost ground to *similar to* over the past century; but my guess is that it is far more common in speech.

  > [image]

  Transitive *like* is never used as an attributive. You should be aware, too, that many authorities regard *like* in this context as a preposition rather than an adjective. It certainly *behaves* like a preposition; but so do adjectives like *ready* and *worth*. Use the analysis that fits your immediate need.

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of set expressions that are more or less common and where you might analyse that "like" is an adjective (though you could possibly analyse that it is a quantifier or other category):

- the phrase "of like mind" and corresponding compound "like-minded"
- the expression "compare like with like"
- in US usage, the legal phrase "like kind" and corresponding compound ("a property of like kind", "a like-kind exchange")

Otherwise, it is occasionally used in formal usage to mean 'similar to the other things mentioned' or 'similar to one another', usually with a plural noun:

> "A family is a categorisation of *like* species."
>
> "Carbon dioxide and other *like* compounds."

Comment: +1 But in *compare like with like* it acts as a noun, as in *We shall not look upon his like again*.

Comment: @StoneyB What makes you jump to that analysis? (It's one *possible* analysis, but another is that they are adjectives. And actually, neither is necessary satisfactory. But I think it's still reasonable to class it within the list of cases that "might" be analysed as adjectives.)

Comment: I suppose properly I should say that *like* there acts as an NP. When an adjective acts as an NP is it still an adjective? Classical grammarians regarded the adjective as a particular syntactical use of a noun, so we've sort of come full circle here.

Comment: @StoneyB So I think the answer to that would be: "it depends on what's useful and consistent for your analysis". As a point of reference and to cut a very long story short, if in "Don't throw [good money] after [bad -]" you say for the purpose of your analysis that 'bad' is "still an adjective" (with some syntactic wrapping around it), then maybe that would make you lean towards saying that 'like' is "still an adjective" in "compare like with like". But... it's arbitrary. What I don't think we can do is simply jump to an unqualified statement that it's "definitely a noun".

Comment: That's why I didn't say it was a noun - I said it *acts* like a noun. (Though my impression is that whatever Orthodoxy there is these days is that word classes are properties not of words but of words-in-contexts.)